# Prevent incompatible Eclipse IDE plugin updates

Tags: eclipse, oomph

I have an Oomph setup for installing Eclipse 2018-12 with a few specific plugins.

In the setup I had to restrict some plugins to older versions, because all later versions of these plugins are incompatible with our build environment.

Eclipse automatically detects new plugin versions periodically and suggest to update these plugin. These new versions are certainly compatible with Eclipse. Technically no other plugin depends on these older plugin versions so I understand why Eclipse sees them as outdated and suggest to update. But since that would break our builds, I would like to prevent Eclipse from trying to update them.

Is there any configuration I can set during the installer to prevent certain plugin updates? Or do I have to completely disable automatic updates?

Comment: You can use your own update site for that. But in your case it would be probably better and be less effort in the long run to fix your build environment to use current instead of outdated software.

Comment: @howlger true, adapting everything to use the latest version would be best. We are currently bound to Eclipse 2018-12 due to other essential plugins that don't support later versions. One plugin that causes issues ships with a known bug which unofrtunately is fixed only in a version that doesn't support 2018-12 any more. There actually is a workaround for the bug but it requires some effort in our case, so I hoped there was an easier way, e.g. by restricting plugins to certain versions.

Comment: A local company-internal update site (p2 repository) is an easy way to control which versions are offered. This update site can be created from an existing Eclipse IDE installation or get the update site by making a [customized Eclipse IDE via Tycho](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized).